# How does one enter women's restroom?

Tags: mass-effect-3

On the Crew Deck of Normandy, we have the restrooms. Throughout the game thus far, I have been able enter men's restroom, but never women's (no hologrammatic lock on it). How do I enter women's? Is it openable at all at certain point in the game? I play a male Shepherd if that makes any difference.

I am not a pervert or anything. Just curious about what's in that room. :-)

Comment: "I play a male Shepherd if that makes any difference." - I would have thought that was obviously the reason :)

Comment: I don't know. Does playing a female open up women's?

Comment: I would assume so - but that's a guess - I've never played the game.

Comment: Yes, playing a female opens women's and locks men's.

Comment: Well, it makes sense that you can only open the male restroom doors if you're a male. I thought that was a little detail that they got right this time round.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One may only enter the bathroom appropriate for one's gender.

If you're **really** curious you could start a character of the opposite gender, though you will likely be disappointed.

Comment: I was tempted to edit that to "you could start a character of the _right_ gender" :)

Comment: It is worth noting that this differs from how the restrooms worked in Mass Effect 2.  In ME2, both restrooms could be entered regardless of Shepard's gender.  However, if you would enter the wrong restroom, EDI would then make a comment pointing you to the correct room.

Comment: @Tacroy Are you assuming OP's gend.... Ok, no